# Learning to build an object in Java

Tags: java, class, object

Hello I'm having a little trouble in understanding this homework. I just started Java a few weeks ago and we just started on building classes so here is the question.

**The problem**: I'm having a trouble with the first constructor and setRadius I generally don't know what to do in them. Do I input into `setRadius` and send that value to that constructor. What do I do with the constructor?

> Write a Circle class that has the following fields:
>
> - **radius**:  a double
> - **PI**:  a final double initialized with the value 3.14159
>
> The class should have the following methods:
>
> - **Constructor**:  accepts the radius of the circle as an argument.
> - **Constructor**:  a no-arg constructor that sets the radius field to 0.0.
> - **setRadius**:  a mutator method for the radius field.
> - **getRadius**:  an accessor method for the radius field.
> - **getArea**:  returns the area of the circle, which is calculated as area = PI * radius * radius.
> - **getDiameter**:  returns the diameter of the circle, which is calculated as diameter = radius * 2.
> - **getCircumference**:  returns the circumference of the circle, which is calculated as circumference  = 2 * PI * radius.
>
> Write a program that demonstrates the Circle class by asking the user for the circle's radius, creating a Circle object, and then reporting the circle's area, diameter, and circumference.

So I wrote this code:

```
public class CircleClass {

    final double PI = 3.14159;
    double radius;

    // this constructor allows the input of the user 
    public CircleClass (double rad){
        radius = rad;
    }

    // this is the default constructor in case of no user input
    public CircleClass (){
        radius = 0;
    }

    // this method allows you to set the radius
    public void setRadius (double input){
        //CircleClass input;
        radius = input;
    }

    // value returners //

    // returns radius
    public double getRadius (){
        return radius;
    }

    // returns area
    public double getArea (){
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }

    // returns diameter
    public double getDiameter(){
        return radius * 2;
    }

    // returns circumference 
    public double getCircumference(){
        return 2 * PI * radius;
    }

}
```

So I'm confused as to the first method and also I may have made a mistake somewhere else in this program if you see something and you think I should know let me know please.

Comment: The program is based on a user input, but there is no way for a user input to happen, I'm assuming you've simply not reached that point of the program yet? Because that is what the setRadius() method is dependant on, as it sets the radius to the input.

Comment: no i have not i just was putting the classes together

Comment: Well that would be necessary for you to understand the setRadius() method. I'll do some changes to the code and I'll try to explain your questions.

Comment: I still dont know what that first constructor does. how do i access its arguments? and if i even did it right

Comment: I'll show you, one sec

Comment: Create an object with constructor in some other class you want to call from. Google for some tutorials http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-constructor-tutorial

Comment: Your constructors initialize the member variable, you have the required methods, it looks fine.  Tho arguably, the `setRadius` method might be better with a more descriptive name for the parameter, like `public void setRadius (double radius) { this.radius = radius; }`.  And perhaps just `Circle` would be a better name for the class.  Then you need to write a class with a main method that asks user for input, creates a Circle object, `Circle c = new Circle(radiusGivenByUser);` ... and prints the desired output by using the getters, `System.out.println("Area :" + c.getArea());` and so on.

Comment: Also, it's generally good practice to leave the word `Class` off of your class name - so that `CircleClass` becomes `Circle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an instance / object of a class, this basically calls the constructor (default / parameterized) constructor of the class.

```
CircleClass circleClass = new CircleClass(10);
```

This will call the parameterized constructor (first constructor in your code) of your class and will set the value of the radius as 10.

```
CircleClass circleClass = new CircleClass();
```

This will call the default constructor (no-arg, second constructor in your code) of your class and will set the value of the radius as 0.

If you want to set the value of the radius using the method `setRadius(double)`, it should be done using an object of the class. Since, the methods of a class can be accessed using the objects of the class.

It can be done as follows:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
CircleClass circleClass = new CircleClass(); // calls the no-arg constructor
System.out.println("Enter the radius of the circle : ");
double radius = in.nextDouble();
circleClass.setRadius(radius); // this sets the radius of the circle using the method setRadius(double) of the class
```

Methods can also be called in java using class names if the method is defined as public static. Consider the code fragment:

```
public class Class1{
   public static final void PrintMessage(){
      System.out.println("Just prints a message");
   }
}
```

The method PrintMessage(void) can be called using the class name as follows:

```
Class1.PrintMessage(); // Calls the method PrintMessage(void)
```

Moreover, I don't see any mistakes in your code given the problem statement.

You might however want to make use of the 'this' variable for your class variables. Many a times we might run out of meaningful names for variables (in your case you have used input as a variable name for radius in your setRadius(double) method which may not make much sense to another programmer). However, if you make use of the 'this' variable you can avoid this.

```
public class CircleClass{
   double radius; // class variable

   public CircleClass(double radius){
      this.radius = radius; // this.radius -> refers to the class variable
   }
   public void setRadius(double radius){
      this.radius = radius; // radius -> refers to the variable passed as argument
   }
}
```

Just a small tip, works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

By creating the main method (the method that actually does something with the program you've created), you might get a better understanding:

First include the below import at the top of your java document (outside the class). This will allow you to use built in java methods that will handle user inputs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then in the main method:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    CircleClass cc = new CircleClass(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.println(cc.getArea());


  }
```

Inside the main method, you first create a Scanner object, that we give the name "input", (from the Scanner class that we imported). This will allow you to take user inputs.

Then create a CircleClass object (that I named cc, you can name it whatever you want). This object is directly referencing the constructor in your class, as in the method with the same name as the class (CircleClass()). Now, since your constructor takes a parameter with the data type double, we also need to provide a "double" parameter when we create the object. Which we set to the user input (input.nextDouble(), <-- This is how you do that using the Scanner class).

Then at the bottom I simply just print out one of the return methods that you created, in this case getArea(). But note that you put cc.getArea(), since "cc" is the name of the CircleClass object. Creating the CircleClass object allows us to use the methods inside of the CircleClass class in that way.

Hope this didn't get too confusing.

Comment: That wasn't one sec, @LinusAronsson.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two instance of CircleClass class.

```
CircleClass uncircle = new CircleClass(); //Default constructor
CircleClass circle = new CircleClass(5.7);
```

The method `uncircle.getRadius()` would return `0`. I suggest you try `circle.getRadius()` to check the output.